# Is there an European Space Agency's innovative advanced concept program? (a NIAC equivalent?)

Tags: planetary-science, esa, space-program

I would like to know if there's an equivalent to NASA's [NIAC](https://www.nasa.gov/content/niac-overview) at ESA. If that's the case, I would like to know if I can read some of these concept studies and what stages of approval they need.

Comment: more "futuristic" than the [General Support Technology Programme (GSTP)](https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Space_Engineering_Technology/Shaping_the_Future/About_the_General_Support_Technology_Programme_GSTP)?

Comment: @JCRM That depends on how futuristc you see NIAC compared to GSTP. I would like to know about the most similar programme to NIAC

Comment: ESA is different compared to NASA in many ways, but a big one is institutional philosophy and politics. NASA, besides getting 3x the amount of money as ESA, is far more partisan-politics-steered and often has big ambitions that are linked to national pride / presidential promises. ESA, being scattered across many nations, generally focuses more on achievable, realistic, and scientific progress with a lower focus on "spectacle" like human spaceflight or moonshot / high risk programs.

Comment: There is overlap between the functions of the ESA Advanced Concepts Team and the NASA NIAC, but you can’t call them equivalent.

http://www.esa.int/gsp/ACT/